# How do I wrap some html around a block in a django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a base template (`base.html`) like this:

```
<doctype html> etc etc
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
```

It is used by many other templates in my site, but I have a third party app that comes with its own templates which inherit from `tp.html` which in turn inherits from `base.html`. These templates are mostly fine but I need their `content` blocks to be wrapped in a div. I could change the third party templates to use a `sub_content` block and modify `tp.html` like so:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="third-party-app">
        {% block sub_content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
{% endbock %}
```

but I don't want to have to modify all the templates in the third party app.

What I want is something similar to `{$smarty.block.child}` found in Smarty templates, or a way to achive the same. Any ideas?

Comment: I think the best you can do is to override those templates. Copy those templates into your template folders and modify them there by including those wrapper element, or by letting them extend some other template.

Answer (score 3):

You can use block.super like so:

3rd party template:

```
  {% block content %}
    <h1>3rd Party Content</h1>
  {% endblock %}
```

your template:

```
{% block content %}
  <div class="wrapper">{{ block.super }}</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In base.html, add pre_content and post_content blocks either side of {% block content %}, then in tp.html add your  and  tags to these blocks. Slightly inelegant, but it'll work and you won't have to modify all your templates.